# redux reset state when changing pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

[image]So i've implemented infinite scroll with redux. Everythings works its just that when I change pages then go back to the home page, it shows the posts i scrolled down to previously. My issue with this is that when i create a new post, it shows all the way at the bottom because its showing the previous posts i scrolled down to first then the newly created post. I've been scouring here and the only thing that sounded logical to me was to reset the state on component unmount. I've created it in my actions and added it to my useEffect and it still dont work. Is there a way when I leave my home page, it will reset so that when i go back to my home page it will fetch all posts again? Im stuck. Help please

HomePage

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const { loading, posts, total } = useSelector((state) => state.posts);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts(page));

    return () => {
      dispatch(resetPosts());
    };
  }, [dispatch, page]);
```

Actions

```
export const getPosts = (page) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const {
      data: { posts, totalPosts },
    } = await api.fetchPosts(page);

    dispatch({
      type: PC.FETCH_ALL_POSTS_SUCCESS,
      payload: { posts, totalPosts },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PC.FETCH_ALL_POSTS_FAIL, payload: error.response });
  }
};
export const resetPosts = () => {
  return { type: PC.RESET_POSTS };
};
```

Reducers

```
export const postsReducer = (state = { posts: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PC.FETCH_ALL_POSTS_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case PC.FETCH_ALL_POSTS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        posts: [...state.posts, ...action.payload.posts],
        total: action.payload.totalPosts,
      };
    case PC.FETCH_ALL_POSTS_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case PC.RESET_POSTS:
      return state;
    case PC.CREATE_POST:
      return { ...state, posts: [...state.posts, action.payload] };
```

Comment: Try resetting your state for the `C.RESET_POSTS`  case clause. E.g. `return { posts: [] }`. Since it looks like you need to manage your state locally to the specific component in question, look into the `useReducer` hook, you'll also be able to reset state using "lazy initialization" in response to an action - which may be suitable for your situation in other ways.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError the reset worked! thank you kind sir. I knew my syntax was off.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are storing your redux state incorrectly. Try edited your logic where you are using the spread operator. It should probably be

```
return {
        loading: false,
        posts: action.payload.posts,
        total: action.payload.totalPosts,
      }
```

This way you are actually updating your state and not making all of your state just one big posts array. I can see what you were trying to do, but that is only really needed if you are doing your return object like

```
return { ...state, posts: action.payload.data }
```

and need to maintain other state variables alongside the posts.

A tool that could help you debug this better in the future is the redux chrome dev tools. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried your method but now my infinite scroll wont work. it just renders up top of page

Comment: @HelpANoobOut you shouldn't have to reset the state in the useEffect, try removing that and using the redux dev tools to see at what point the posts are getting duplicated. Update you question with either screenshots from the dev tools if you can or more details on the timing of the post duplication. I don't see anything else wrong with the redux setup and can't really help with the infinite scroll without seeing the rest of the application.

Comment: Sorry i shouldnt have said times two, it doesn't. Edited!  So im at home page, i scroll to the bottom and get my posts. I change pages then go back to home. It shows all the posts i scrolled down to previously and then the extra posts that dispatches when you go to hompage. so the reason for my concern is because when i create a post, it doesnt show up to the top. Instead it shows all the way on the bottom. Thats why i was wondering if you can reset the state or are there any other ways around it?